# Understanding this Lagrangian calculation

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, notation, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I was trying to understand [this section of a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Lagrangian_approach):

> $$0 = \delta \int \sqrt{2T} d\tau =
>   \int \frac{\delta T}{\sqrt{2T}} d\tau =
>   \frac{1}{c} \delta \int T d\tau$$

For the life of me, I can't figure out how does one get from $\displaystyle \delta \int \sqrt{2T} d\tau$ to $\displaystyle \int \frac{\delta T}{\sqrt{2T}} d\tau$. What is $\delta$? I assume it is some kind of differential operator but in respect to what variable?

Comment: $\delta$ is the symbol for “[first variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_variation)” in the [calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_variations). See the first equation in that section. The *entire* worldline function $x^\mu(\tau)$ is being varied, but small variations of a geodesic make no first-order change to its length.

Comment: @Ghoster Thanks, so let $f(x^{\mu})=\sqrt{2T}$ $\displaystyle \delta \int \sqrt{f(x^{\mu})} d\tau = \frac{d}{d\alpha} \int \sqrt{f(x^{\mu}+\nu (\tau))} d\tau |_{\alpha = 0}$? I am not sure why $\delta$ is still there in $\displaystyle \int \frac{\delta T}{\sqrt{2T}} d\tau$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I was trying to understand [this section of a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Lagrangian_approach):

> $$0 = \delta \int \sqrt{2T} d\tau =
>   \int \frac{\delta T}{\sqrt{2T}} d\tau =
>   \frac{1}{c} \delta \int T d\tau$$

> For the life of me, I can't figure out how does one get from $\displaystyle \delta \int \sqrt{2T} d\tau$ to $\displaystyle \int \frac{\delta T}{\sqrt{2T}} d\tau$.

Let the function $T(\tau)$ be changed to another function that is "close" to $T(\tau)$:
$$
T(\tau) \to T(\tau) + \epsilon \eta(\tau)\;,
$$
where $\eta(\tau)$ is a function and $\epsilon$ is "small" constant in a sense we will describe more below.

We note that the relationship between our notation and the  Wikipedia notation is:
$$
\delta T = \epsilon \eta(\tau)\;,
$$
where our notation makes explicit that the variation $\delta T$ of $T$ is an arbitrary function  $\eta(\tau)$ times a "small" expansion parameter $\epsilon$.

We literally make the above replacement in the integral of interest:
$$
I = \int \sqrt{2T}d\tau \to \int \sqrt{2T+2\epsilon \eta(\tau)}d\tau\;,
$$
and then we look at *only the first order change* in the integral with respect to $\epsilon$. We look at the first order change because the *integrand* of the first order change in $I$ is what we *define* as the *functional* derivative of $I$ (in analogy with the derivative of a multivariate function). We are "allowed" to do this because $\epsilon$ is "small" in the sense that we can ignore all the higher order terms in the $\epsilon$ expansion.

Expanding to first order in epsilon can be performed in this case via the known McLauren/Taylor series for the function $\sqrt{1+x}$. (Which is $\sqrt{1+x} \approx 1 + x/2 + \ldots$, where the terms being ignored are of order $x^2$ and higher.)

$$
\int \sqrt{2T+2\epsilon \eta(\tau)}d\tau 
=\int \sqrt{2T}\sqrt{1+\frac{\epsilon \eta(\tau)}{T}}d\tau 
\approx \int \sqrt{2T}\left({1+\frac{\epsilon \eta(\tau)}{2T}}\right)d\tau
\equiv I + \delta I\;,
$$
where, now we see that:
$$
\delta I = \int \sqrt{2T}\left({\frac{\epsilon \eta(\tau)}{2T}}\right)d\tau
=\int \frac{\epsilon \eta(\tau)}{\sqrt{2T}}d\tau
\equiv\int \frac{\delta T}{\sqrt{2T}}d\tau\;.
$$

We could also write this result as a functional derivative, by definition of the latter, as:
$$
\frac{\delta I}{\delta T(\tau)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2T}}
$$

Comment: Thank you, it is more complicated than I thought... Regarding your last remark, how did you get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2T}}$? I thought $\frac{\delta I}{\delta T(\tau)} = \frac{\int \frac{\delta T}{\sqrt{2T}}d\tau}{\epsilon \eta(\tau)}$? Also, I don't understand the purpose of doing this whole rigamarole when one could use EL equation directly like this: $\frac{d}{d\tau} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{x}^{\sigma}} (\sqrt{2T}) \right) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\sigma}} (\sqrt{2T})$.

Comment: In the answer I wrote that the *definition* of the functional derivative is the **integrand** of the change. This means that, by definition, the functional derivative is $\frac{\delta I}{\delta T(\tau)}$m where: $\delta I \equiv \int \frac{\delta I}{\delta T(\tau)}d\tau$.

Comment: You want to think of $\tau$ as a *continuous* analog of a discrete index $i$ in normal multivariable calculus. You want to think of it like: $\delta f = \sum_i\frac{df}{dx_i}\delta x_i \to \int  \frac{\delta f}{\delta T(\tau)}\delta T(\tau)d\tau$.

Comment: You will find all of this explained in more detail in a textbook on variational calculus. Sorry, I don't have a good one to recommend.

Comment: @RaySiplao The purpose of the whole rigamarole is to derive the Euler-Lagrange equations. For example, the result $\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}=0$ follows from varying the action $S = \int dt L(x(t),\dot x(t))$ with respect to $x(t)$. Unless you know how to perform the calculus of variations you can not derive the EL equations from the stationary action principle.

Comment: EDIT: in one of my previous comments the "m" after $\delta I/\delta T$ should just be a comma ",". This was a typo, but it is too late to edit the comment.

Answer (score 0):

$T(\tau)$ is a function. $dT(\tau)$ is also a function that is "small" i.e. less than some $\epsilon$ for all $\tau$. $T(\tau) + \delta T(\tau)$ means you perturb the function by adding a small perturbation at all $\tau$. If you do this then $\sqrt{2(T + \delta T)} \approx \frac{\delta T}{\sqrt{2T}}$. Here you kind of Taylor expand the function at each $\tau$ (also the arguments of the functions are suppressed for brevity). $\delta(F(T))$ means the expression you get when substituting $T + \delta T$ for $T$ in $F$, so $\delta\sqrt{2T} \equiv \sqrt{2(T+\delta T)}$.

To better understand all of this I would suggest reading a good textbook on the calculus of variations. There are many around (this is a relatively old discipline of mathematics).